# POST Variable Array and filter_input

Tags: php, arrays, variables, post, input

While using `filter_input`, I'm not able to pull in a `POST` array variable. The `POST` input:

```
type              => 'container',
action            => 'edit',
data[display]     => 1,
data[query_limit] => 100
```

I can access the `data` variable from the `$_POST` superglobal correctly as an array, but the [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function returns nothing:

```
$data   = $_POST['data']; // Working, woot
$data   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data'); // returns null, should return array
$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action'); // returns "edit" (correctly)
```

Is it not possible to use `filter_input` for a `POST` array variable?

Comment: isn't `filter_input_array()` the one you need?

Comment: no it is not! https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input-array.php

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try :

```
$data   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
```

Links:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php

Comment: Nice, works perfectly. Seems like it should be more straightforward than this for something as common as what I'm doing :)

Comment: Agreed - at least you'd think the php manual would include a note or something.

Answer (score 14):

`FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` will return false if the `POST` variable contains a scalar value. If you're unsure or just intend on the `POST` variable accepting both scalar and array values, use `FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY` instead, which will treat any input as an array, essentially casting scalar values accordingly.

```
$data = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used FormData in javascript and post the fields with jquery ajax.
The way I receive all these field is:

```
$arrFields = array('field1','field2','field2','field3', 'field4','field5');
foreach($arrFields as $field){
   $params[$field] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $field, FILTER_DEFAULT);
}
var_dump($params);
```

Then I will get all the data into an array which I can pass on...

Comment: try using filter_input_array();

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can do your filtering in one shot...for example

```
$MY_INPUT = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, [
    "item_id" => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
    "item_string_code" => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    "method" => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    "item_id_array" => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
        'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY
    )
]);
```

The result is almost the same as the post data in terms of what you get back except instead of the global $_POST being your variable it will be $MY_INPUT in this case.